# barplot in ggplot returning a single bar not expected 30

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's some dummy data:

```
> print(ggdf)
           Sessions
2017-01-01    80510
2017-01-02    82500
2017-01-03    80496
2017-01-04    81913
2017-01-05    79714
2017-01-06    80236
2017-01-07    82163
2017-01-08    81525
2017-01-09    79738
2017-01-10    81411
2017-01-11    84069
2017-01-12    80991
2017-01-13    81350
2017-01-14    81016
2017-01-15    79220
2017-01-16    81638
2017-01-17    80597
2017-01-18    83716
2017-01-19    80657
2017-01-20    81872
2017-01-21    81496
2017-01-22    79307
2017-01-23    79062
2017-01-24    80101
2017-01-25    82178
2017-01-26    77641
2017-01-27    81067
2017-01-28    85379
2017-01-29    81833
2017-01-30    80927
```

It's a df with just 30 observations and a variable for date.

```
> str(ggdf)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Sessions: num  80510 82500 80496 81913 79714 ...
```

I want to trend the metric for 30 days in a barplot.

I can get it working in base r, but not in ggplot:

```
myplot <- ggplot(data = ggdf,
                 aes(x = "Date", y = "Sessions")) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
myplot
```

Here's a screen of how it looks:
[image]

I was expecting/hoping to see 30 bars along the date range, the first bar being for 80,510, all the way along to 80,927.

What have I missed here?

Comment: You don't have a `Date` column as per the `str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `str(ggdf)`, there is no 'Date' column, it is just rownames.  We can create a 'Date' column and then do the `ggplot`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
rownames_to_column(ggdf, "Date") %>%
      mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
      ggplot(., aes(x= Date, y = Sessions)) + 
                      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
                      scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

[image]

#### Update

From the comments, the OP created a 'Date' column, but still got the output in the OP's post.   It can be traced back to the quoted string in `aes`.  For strings, use the `aes_string`

```
ggplot(data = ggdf, aes_string(x="Date", y = "Sessions")) + 
                  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

otherwise, just use without any quotes

```
ggplot(data = ggdf, aes(x=Date, y = Sessions)) +
                   geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. Any idea why when I added a date column just using cbind this did not work?

Comment: @DougFir In your comments, I find that your 'Date' column is `factor` which may not work well for ordering.

Comment: Thanks again for answering. What do you think of this data causing the same problem? > str(ggdf1)
'data.frame': 30 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Sessions: num  80510 82500 80496 81913 79714 ...
 $ dates   : Date, format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-02" "2017-01-03" "2017-01-04" ...
>

Comment: @DougFir  You don't need quotes i.e. `ggplot(data = ggdf, aes(x=Date, y = Sessions)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: @DougFir  If you want to use a string object i.e. objects that store the value `ggplot(data = ggdf, aes_string(x="Date", y = "Sessions")) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")`